# Selenium with NUnit and .Net giving NoSuchElementExcpection

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, nunit

I am using selenium for automated testing. When the test runs on Selenium IDE it runs successfully then, when exporting it as a .Net web driver and run it with NUnit the NoSuchElementsException is being thrown. Do someone what is causing this exception please?

```
SeleniumTests.UserNotLogged.TheUserNotLoggedTest:
```

OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":""} //Exception from NUnit

```
[Test]
    public void TheUserNotLoggedTest()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "Index.aspx");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("wrapper")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Home")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("News")).Click(); //Exception thrown here
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Events")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Contact Us")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Register")).Click();
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these kind of cases, it's generally a timing issue. I take it these are navigation links? In which case, it could well be that Selenium is trying to find the News link well before the page has finished loading. Try adding in a WebDriverWait:

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

If this still doesn't solve it, move to a different method of finding the links, such as a css selector or XPath - just to verify that you CAN find it using a different method (albeit not the best one).

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is still throwing the exception

Comment: I assume you can get to 'Events' without needing to click on 'News' - so remove the clicking of the News link - does it fail on the 'Events' one instead? If so, it's definitely a timing issue. Try using another method, do the links have classes on them? At the very least, try using XPath, for example:     driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()='News']");

Comment: I have another page containing this  driver.FindElement(By.Id("drpList")).Click(); and again its throwing the exception, can and drop down list be done with XPath?

Comment: Absolutely, dropdown's are usually 'Select' elements, with each option inside the dropdown being an 'option' element, so the XPath to select the actual dropdown would be, assuming "drpList" is the ID of the dropdown: "//select[@id='drpList']"

Does that help?